# 小鳥のキス is this an expression or does it mean something else?

Tags: meaning, translation

> ただ小鳥のキスように.

This is the whole sentence.

What is a 小鳥のキス?

Is it a kind of kiss? Or is it referring to a kind of birds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

バードキス is a *type of kiss*. The idea is that the shape of your lips resemble a bird's beak. This could be called "the usual kiss".

小鳥のキス (小鳥 = small bird), presumably references バードキス and means a small/light/innocent/no-funny-business type of kiss.